# mysql query - How to write if condition on where

Tags: jquery, mysql, database

i have query for checking if close_at >= '00:00' + interval 1 day else not add interval. my query is:

select * from table where now() between open_at and if(close_at >= '00:00' close_at + INTERVAL 1 day, close_at - INTERVAL 1 day)

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please provide a [mcve] including expected and actual results.

Comment: explain this part 'where '23:00' between open_at and if(close_at >= '00:00' close_at + INTERVAL 1 day, close_at - INTERVAL 1 day)'

Comment: You cannot perform a calculation in a WHERE.  You would need to select that value and use HAVING

Comment: share your sample data expected output

Comment: for example, i have data:

no | open_at | close_at
1 | 08:00 | 23:00
2 | 08:00 | 00:00
3 | 09:00 | 02:00

how do i write query for select time now if close_at >= 00:00 i must add interval 1 day , else don't add interval 1 day

@ZaynulAbadinTuhin

Answer (score 0):

In where condition, you can write case when conditions based on your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  `id` ,  `naam` 
FROM  `klanten` 
WHERE IF('close_at' >= '00:00' 'close_at' + INTERVAL 1 day, 'close_at' - INTERVAL 1 day) LIKE  'some condition'

The structure is like this but i dont know what is a constant or a attribute, use the simple quote correctly.